# Is it possible to disable all alerts() in page

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

i am using selenium and i want to disable all alerts() in webpage.

```
ExecuteScript("document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('alert(', '');");
```

I tried the above script, but don't have the behaviour that I want.

The code replace but the alert still fired!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that this would work:

```
ExecuteScript("alert = function() { }");
```

It will replace the `alert` method with an empty function.

Answer (score 1):

```js
ExecuteScript("window.alert = function(){}");
```